# Is there a way to create invisible text?

Tags: windows-8, encryption, passwords, text-editing

I would like to create a text file (the format doesn't matter) whose text is invisible. I don't mean a hidden file. A normal file with invisible, copiable text. Or could it be displayed the way passwords are displayed, as asterisks or dots? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Basically I want to keep myself from acessing certain websites (you're free to guess). I guess I need to find a different way of solving this.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want, but what's wrong with an office or web document with the text the same colour as the background?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to keep myself from acessing certain websites (you're free to guess). I guess I need to find a different way of solving this.

Comment: This sounds like a human problem rather than a computer problem.  Also, from your comments, your question is incomplete.  The requirements aren't just invisibility, but also something you can't reverse, which is a different problem.

Comment: Why taking all this trouble? Why not just encrypt the file?

Comment: You could look for alternative solutions...such as blocking those sites in your network router or your host file (or using some software like K9 Web Protection).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could colour the font the same as the background, e.g. white. Any rich text editor will allow this... Word Pad on Windows, and TextEdit on mac, will both read .rtf format and white font will be invisible. The text will be selectable and copyable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that the text becomes visible upon highlighting. I think I'll do some more googling.

Answer (score 3):

OK, it sounds like you may need to use some web type environment. Here's some food for thought, based on your idea of asterisks. Copy the code below into a notepad, and save it as whateveryouwant.hta (file extension must be hta):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Masked Text with Copy</title>

        <HTA:APPLICATION 
             ID="HTAUI" 
             APPLICATIONNAME="Masked Text with Copy"
             SCROLL="no"
             SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
             WINDOWSTATE="maximized"
        >
    </head>

    <style>
    BODY
    {
       background-color: #b3c7e0;
       font-family: Arial;
       font-size: 8pt;
       margin-top: 2px;
       margin-left: 8px;
       margin-right: 3px;
       margin-bottom: 3px;
    }

    </style>

    <script language="VBScript">

    Sub Window_Onload
        self.Focus()
        self.ResizeTo 372,72
    end sub

    Sub copyTextClick
        strCopy = MaskedTextBox.Value 
        document.parentwindow.clipboardData.SetData "text", strCopy 
    End Sub

    </script>

    <body>
        <p align="left">
            <font face="Arial" size="2">Masked TextBox</font> <input type="password" name="MaskedTextBox" size="20" value="Secret Text!">
            <input type="button" value="Copy Text" onclick="copyTextClick" name="copyText">
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then launch the .hta, and you'll see this:

[image]

The textbox is set as password type which results in the masking, but it also forbids the user from using a normal copy command. So you have to get the text programmatically and set it to the clipboard - hence the 'Copy Text' button.

I know this is only one step of your overall process, but hopefully it is useful food for thought?

Answer (score -1):

Here is what you can do.

1. Open command prompt and change to directory of your choice e.g. `cd desktop`
2. Type `notepad filename.txt`. This will ask to create a file. Click `yes` to create the file. Write something if you want to.
3. Now you need to hide your data behind this file. Means if anyone opens the file, he can only see `filename.txt` data.
4. Type `notepad filename:txt:secret_message.txt`. Create the file and put your secret message in it.
5. `secret_message.txt` is not visible at all even though it exists.
6. You can open `secret_message.txt` by typing `notepad filename:txt:secret_message.txt` to see the secret message.

Comment: It's not "bug", it's the [Alternate Data Stream](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2013/03/24/alternate-data-streams-in-ntfs.aspx)

Comment: No, Streams.exe can easily show all streams. And Microsoft deliberately choose to not show the stream in Windows Explorer, and documented it as such.